# Find the vertices of a square of center $0$ knowing that one of them is $(3,4)$ using Complex analysis

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

> Considering how to calculate $n$-th roots of a complex number in polar form, find the vertices of a square of center $0$ knowing that one of them is $(3,4)$.

---

Ok so I don't know how to express the equation. I know that $w\in\Bbb{C}$ is a $n$-rooth of $z\in\Bbb{C}$ iff $z=w^n$.

In this case we have $n=4$ (because it is a square) and $v_1=3+4i=[5,\arctan(4/3)]$, so **Question: the equation becomes $z=v^4$?**

Now call $z=[\rho,\varphi]$ and $v=[r,\theta]$. We need to find all $v$ such that $z=v^4$, i.e. $v_k$ for $k\in[1,4]$.

Then $v^4=[r^4,4\theta]$, so by equality of complex numbers in polar coordinates, we have $\rho=r^4$ and $4\theta=\varphi+2k\pi$. Then $v_k=[\sqrt[4]{\rho},(\varphi+2k\pi)/4]$.

Since $v_1=[5,\arctan(4/3)]$ and for the calculated formula $v_1=[\sqrt[4]{\rho},(\varphi+2\pi)/4]$, then $5=\sqrt[4]{\rho}$ and $\arctan(4/3)=(\varphi+2\pi)/4$, hence $\rho=625$ and $\varphi=4\arctan(4/3)-2\pi$.

From here I don't know how to proceed.

**Question: How do we calculate $v_2,v_3$ and $v_4$?** We could use the polar form of $v_k$ to also find $v_1$ to check if the formula is correct.

**EDIT** I think my calculations are correct! We end up with $$v_k=\left[5,\frac{4\arctan(4/3)-2\pi+2k\pi}{4}\right]$$ so: $$v_1=[5,\arctan(4/3)]=(3,4)\\
v_2=[5,(4\arctan(4/3)-2\pi+4\pi)/4]=(-4,3)\\
v_3=[5,(4\arctan(4/3)-2\pi+6\pi)/4]=(-3,-4)\\
v_4=[5,(4\arctan(4/3)-2\pi+8\pi)/4]=(4,-3).$$

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Each vertex is a 90-degree rotation from the previous. A 90-degree rotation is a multiplication by a 4th root of unity. So....

Answer (score 1):

They are the roots of $z^4=625$, rotated by $\arctan3/4$.  The former are $5e^{k\pi i/2},\,k=0,1,2,3$.

Let $w=4+3i$.  So, you can use a primitive fourth root of unity, say $e^{πi/2}=i$, to rotate by $\pi/2$ a few times.  Get $w,iw,i^2w,i^3w$ as the vertices. That is, $4+3i,-3+4i,-4-3i,3-4i$.

In polar, it's $5e^{i\arctan3/4},5e^{i(\arctan3/4+\pi/2)},5e^{i(\arctan3/4+\pi)},5e^{i(\arctan3/4+3\pi/2)}$.

Comment: I need to use the polar form of a complex number, not the exponential form.

Comment: Use $5e^{i\arctan3/4}$.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use exponential form.

You're given one root as $z= 3+4i$.

The other roots are $iz, i^2z = -z, i^3z = -iz$. This is basically from rotating the position vector by $\frac{\pi} {2}$ counterclockwise each time.

So the answers (including the given vertex first) are $(3,4);(-4,3);(-3,-4);(4,-3)$.

Comment: Thanks! But the exercise is clear: we must use the formula of the $n$-rooth of a complex number somewhere.

Comment: Well, the four solutions of $x^4=1$ are...? Those are the fourth roots of unity. When you multiply them in turn by a single fourth root of any complex number, you get all the other roots cyclically. I like to keep things simple. I don't see how your teacher can fault you if you demonstrate a deeper understanding that simplifies the solution.

Comment: Where did you use the required formula?

Comment: Solve $x^4 = 1 = e^{2k\pi i}$. Find each value in rectangular form. There's your formula.